# Bitmap.Save() throws generic GDI+ error or ArgumentException

Tags: c#, xna

This is my code:

```
save.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory+ "/Content/map.png");
save.Dispose();
```

I have no idea why this throws a generic GDI+ error.
If I change it to

```
save.Dispose();
save.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory+ "/Content/map.png");
```

it will throw a ArgumentException because of a invalid parameter.

Comment: Have you checked what is Environment.CurrentDirectory? It is well know that you get surprising results with this call.

Comment: I did and corrected my code. But it doesn´t work.

Comment: You get that exception when it can't save the file for *any* reason.  Like Environment.CurrentDirectory not being set to the directory you hope it is.

Comment: Calling "Dispose" before calling another function of that object can't be a good idea.

Comment: did you try using '\' instead of '/' in the path?

Answer (score 0):

try saving the path to a FileInfo object

```
FileInfo lInfo = new FileInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Content/map.png");
save.Save(lInfo.FullName);
save.Dispose();
```

this will ensure that the filename is in valid format. Also make sure you have administrative rights to that directory, or that visual studio is running as administrator.

This does NOT work on monogame, if you are trying to save a texture2D to a bitmap, just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that

```
`FileInfo lInfo = new FileInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Content/map.png");`
```

will work? as far as i know, you have to use

```
`FileInfo lInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"content\map.png"));`
```

or

```
`FileInfo lInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "//content//map.png"))`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Path.Combine` with direrctory and file and this method will return the path.

Example:

```cs
string file = "map.png";
string dir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, file);

save.Save(path);
save.Dispose();
```